# Call to undefined method JXMLElement::getElementByPath()

Tags: joomla, components

I tried to install ip filter module in joomla 2.5 .while installing i got the fatal error as
**Call to undefined method JXMLElement::getElementByPath()** in com_ipfilter\install\install.php on line 9

i cant find any help.

can any1 helpto solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what have you tried to solve this error?

Comment: its because of version compatibility of that ip filter module

Answer (score 1):

Your component, com_ipfilter apparently is for an old version of Joomla, i.g. Joomla 1.5, and Joomla. So you have two options

1. Rewrite and old component to work with a new version of Joomla (need know PHP programming)
2. Just look for one alternative and do not use this extension.

If you want the second suggestion, look in special on these extensions http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=ip+block